# $W^{m,p}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^d) = W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and continuously imbedded

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Can anyone help me solve the following results?
If $1\leq p < \infty$, then

(a) $W^{m,p}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^d) = W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$,

(b) $W^{m,p}_{0}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W_{m,p}(\Omega)$, (continuously imbedded),

where $W^{m,p}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ the closure in $ W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)(test function)$ and

$W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is space sobolev.

Comment: The linked question only answers (a), but (b) is trivial (of course a subspace with the same norm is continuously embedded).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \cap W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is dense in $W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with respect to the Sobolev norm. Now show that $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is dense in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \cap W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with respect to the Sobolev norm. To this end, note that if $u \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, we can approximate it - in $L^{p}$ - by a function with compact support.

Comment: $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not even contained in $W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. But its intersection with $W^{m,p}$ is indeed dense in $W^{m,p}$. And integrable smooth functions do not necessarily vanish at infinity.

Comment: @MaoWao I meant that they vanish in $L^{p}$ but thanks that was unclear from what I wrote.